# Плагин для eclipse, использующий qt

Tags: java, c++, qt, eclipse

Имеется некое оконное приложение написанное с помощью `Qt`. Есть ли возможность встроить его в `eclipse`? Я знаю, что плагины для него можно писать только на `Java`, но есть же такая вещь как `jni` и можно обернуть функционал написанный на `c++` для использования в `Java` классе, но можно ли сделать так с виджетами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать ваше QT приложение "внутри" Eclipse в качестве его плагина, то нет - скорее всего нельзя. Для создания планигов в Eclipse используется технология OSGI, в качетстве графического интерфейса используется интерфейс самого Eclipse (SWT/JFace). На этот счёт есть множество учебников и пособий. Например, см. [Eclipse IDE Plug-in Development](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugin/article.html). Но справедливости ради должен заметить, что существует продукт IBM Domino Designer, где IBM удалось как-то "вставить" в оболочку Eclipse большую часть легаси приложения, полностью написанного на C. Вместе с частями сишного GUI. Но я лично нигде не встречал информацию как такое можно сделать.